# Only line-break/word-wrap URLs at the end of the line

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have a div which contains a URL. I want the URL to stretch to the end of the line then wrap around to the next line only at the end of the line.

For example this is what happens with 'word-wrap: break-word' in FF9:

```
http://www.somewebsiteaddressthathopefullydoesntexist.com
/aaaa_aaaa_aaaa_aaaa_aaaa_aaaa_aaaa_aaaa_aaaa_aaaa
```

But I would like it to look more like this

```
http://www.somewebsiteaddressthathopefullydoesntexist.com/aaaa_aaaa_aaaa_aaaa_
aaaa_aaaa_aaaa_aaaa_aaaa_aaaa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured out a solution, put `<wbr>` between each character:

```
$myURL = "http://www.somewebsiteaddressthathopefullydoesntexist.com/aaaa_aaaa_aaaa_aaaa_aaaa_aaaa_aaaa_aaaa_aaaa_aaaa";

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($myURL); $i+=6){
    $myURL = substr($myURL,0,$i)."<wbr>".substr($myURL, $i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try the `<wbr>` (wordbreak) tag. http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_wbr.asp.
(It will only break there (and only there) if there is no space left, it is not the same as `<br />`)

Comment: This would require knowing where to split the URL up before-hand (which I don't!), or using a fixed width font and adding that tag in after a fixed amount of characters - which seems a bit hacky, but this may be the only option

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour regarding punctuations such as `/` (slash) differs a little bit between browser. See [this JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qE3b9/). In Firefox 10.0.2 it will break before the solidus, while Opera breaks after. The rest of the line will break correctly if you use `word-wrap:break-word;`. Unless there's a nobreak slash entity you won't find a cross-browser solution. See also [Wiki: Slash (punctuation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_%28punctuation%29#In_English_text):

> The slash is also used to indicate a line break when quoting multiple lines from a poem, play, or headline.

Opera:
[image: Operascreenshot - break after /]
Firefox:
[image: Firefox screenshot - break before /]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested the `overflow` css option - [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)?

Comment: I guess the start of the URL is the most important bit anyway, so I'll use white-space:nowrap; and overflow:hidden; for now (but not really the solution I was after), thanks anyway :)